# Elasticsearch's search_after doesn't work with date

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch query that looks something like this,

```
{
  size: 25,
  query: {
    bool: {
      filter: ...,
      must: ...
    }
  },
  sort: [
    {
      created_at: {
        order: "desc
      }
    },
    {
      id: {
        order: "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  from: 0,
  search_after: ["2018-10-25T18:04:13.488Z", "8"]
}
```

When I run this I get an error saying,

> "reason": Failed to parse search_after value for field [created_at],
>   caused_by":{"type":"number_format_exception","reason":"For input
>   string: \"2018-10-23T21:41:03.167Z\"

I tried mapping the `created_at` property with type of `date` and format of `date_time`, but that didn't seem to help.

Can anyone shed some light on how I can solve this?

Comment: You need to pass the date as the number of milliseconds since epoch, i.e. instead of `2018-10-25T18:04:13.488Z` try passing `1540491254488`

Comment: Would this require saving the date in number of milliseconds since epoch in the first place? Actually I had tried this and was getting ```undefined method `iso8601` for 1540491254488:Fixnum```

Comment: No you can continue indexing your documents as you do now, but when creating your query, you need to feed that number into `search_after`

Comment: That worked! Thank you :bow:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the date as the number of milliseconds since epoch, i.e. instead of `2018-10-25T18:04:13.488Z` try passing `1540491254488`

```
{
  size: 25,
  query: {
    bool: {
      filter: ...,
      must: ...
    }
  },
  sort: [
    {
      created_at: {
        order: "desc
      }
    },
    {
      id: {
        order: "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  from: 0,
  search_after: [1540491254488, "8"]
                       ^
                       |
                  change this
```

Note that you can continue indexing your documents as you do now, but when creating your query, you need to feed that number into `search_after`.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, the Elasticsearch documentation is misleading on this, as their [example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-after.html) looks like:

```
    "search_after": [1463538857, "654323"],
```

which leads you to believe that it is seconds, rather than milliseconds, since the epoch.

Answer (score 0):

When sorting on a date field, Elastic Search will always return `sort` value in `epoch_millis`, even if you have defined a different format in your mapping.

It's explained in the docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html):

"Note that the sort values that are returned are all in milliseconds-since-the-epoch."

So if you have defined a different format and rely on the `sort` to implement pagination, you need to convert from `epoch_millis` to your desired format. Probably the easiest way to fix this is to include `epoch_millis` in your date mappings format, ie:

```
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "date": {
        "type":   "date",
        "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
      }
    }
  }
```

Reference [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html#date-epoch-seconds)